# Unstable p-values in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, p-value, modeling

I'm tweaking a logistic regression model in R. The model's been optimized and tested pretty extensively so far.

I need to remove one variable for non-statistical reasons (`varH` below) but doing so causes another of my p values to jump (for `varI`). Because I had been using a 0.05 cutoff, I then go to remove `varI` - which causes the p value for `varA` to jump!

What's going on here?

The below table shows actual p-values for the three models. `0.0000`'s are small but not `<2.00E-16` small.

```
        mdl1       mdl2         mdl3
varA    0.0074     0.0472    -> 0.0568 <-
varB    0.0000     0.0000       0.0000
varC    0.0001     0.0053       0.0044
varD    0.0104     0.0008       0.0010
varE    0.0000     0.0000       0.0000
varF    0.0000     <2.00E-16    <2.00E-16
varG    0.0057     0.0054       0.0049
varH    0.0000     (cut)        (cut)
varI    0.0135  -> 0.2532 <-    (cut)
varJ    0.0031     0.0023       0.0034
```

Comment: It might be informative to compare the coefficients not the p-values.

Comment: have you tested multicollinearity?

Comment: Coefficients change only slightly in some cases, and one changes sign, which is interesting. As for multicolinearity - VIFs before the change above are all pretty low (below 2) and stay that way.